# Escaping characters in PHP and retaining

Tags: php, mysql, insert, escaping, mysql-real-escape-string

I have an app in PHP , I am getting first Name and last Name from several sources, (API's ,files etc)
Suppose I get Name like `john'`, `john"`, How I can save the name as it is in the Database, the `',"` could be at any place,The problem is that when I write query like

```
Insert into table values('".$a."');
```

so If $a contains name John' then the query becomes `Insert into table values('John'');` which is wrong,`( 2 ' at the end)` How to cater these scenario in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: You have to use parameterized query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$string);
```

> This function is used to create a legal SQL string that you can use in an SQL statement. The given string is encoded to an escaped SQL string, taking into account the current character set of the connection.

**[Reference](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string)**

Comment: so should it retain the John' in the DB?

Comment: Yes it will retain that

Comment: it converted it in to John/'

Comment: No it is not, why don't you give it a try? it will be saved as John'